# Searching through a string or xml type in entity framework, what is the fastest?

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework

I'm using entity framework and I have a string field I'm using to hold ids separated by commas. There will never be more than ~30 ids in any string, but I might have millions of rows to search.
ex. "435,6789,1231,232"

I know I can search through the string for specific ids like this below with .Contains()

```
var events = dbContext.YogaSpaceEvents.Where(i => i.RegisteredStudentIds.Contains("12345") && i.EventDateTime >= DateTime.Now);
```

But will this run really slowly with millions of records?
If so, is there a better approach or column type I can use, like xml that will run much faster when I have millions of rows?

It's hard for me to test because I would need to populate millions of rows!

Comment: Stop storing multiple pieces of data in one field as CSV, and properly normalize your data, and you don't have to worry about the comparisons of two hugely inefficient methods of searching.

Comment: The fastest method is to use a hash table.  So I would take all the csv ids and create a dictionary which contain the ids as the key and the row number as the value(s).  So if you have multiple rows that contain the same id the Dictionary would be Dictionary<int, List<int>> dict.  Then build the dictionary.  Then do your search which will reduce the search time.

Answer (score 0):

It will probably run slower than needed. Just create a table named Registrations with EventId and StudentId as the primary key and you'll be rocket fast :)

On the code side, it will looks something like:

```
var student = dbContext.Students.FindById(12345); 
var events = student.Events.Where(i.EventDateTime >= DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: the only thing I'm worried about here is what happens when that table grows to millions or perhaps billions of records. I want to keep the table size relatively small. right?

Comment: Side question - can I create a table with 2 primary keys (EventId, StudentId) ?

Comment: If you make EventId and StudentId the primary key then lookups will be fast.

Comment: You want to make *both* EventId and StudentId part of the same key so that one student can only register for the same event once.

Comment: couldn't I also just create a table that has a foriegn key to YogaSpaceEvents?

Comment: That's what I'm proposing: creating a table with EvenId being a FK into the YogaSpaceEvents table and StudentId being a FK into the Students table. Both will be part of the PK of the new table.

Comment: It's a very common approach called 'junction table'. E.g. http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do this in the code. I'll post some solution below to see if it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

here is what I have so far, I have an event and I want to keeps records of the students registered so I can say "what events is student '12345' registered for?" and then return those events

```
public class YogaSpaceEvent
{
    public YogaSpaceEvent() {}

    [Key]
    public int YogaSpaceEventId { get; set; }

    [Index]
    public int YogaSpaceRefId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("YogaSpaceRefId")]
    public virtual YogaSpace YogaSpace { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index]
    public DateTime EventDateTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public YogaTime Time { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public YogaSpaceDuration Duration { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RegisteredStudents> RegisteredStudents { get; set; }
}
```

Here is RegisteredStudents

```
public class RegisteredStudents  
 {
    public RegisteredStudents () {}

    [Key]
    public int RegisteredStudentsId { get; set; }

    [Index]
    public int YogaSpaceEventRefId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("YogaSpaceEventRefId")]
    public virtual YogaSpaceEvent YogaSpaceEvent { get; set; }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
}
```

and now I can say

```
var events = dbContext.RegisteredStudents.Where(i => i.StudentId == 12345).Select(j => j.YogaSpaceEvent);
```